# What is the use of ThisType in Java?

Tags: java

I am using Java and I am trying to investigate and learn from the source code of sqlbuilder from healthmarketscience. You can get the source code by adding [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.healthmarketscience.sqlbuilder/sqlbuilder/3.0.2) maven dependency.

The file BaseCreateQuery.class has the following code

```
public abstract class BaseCreateQuery<ThisType extends BaseCreateQuery<ThisType>> extends Query<ThisType> {
    protected SqlObject _object;
    protected SqlObjectList<SqlObject> _columns = SqlObjectList.create();

    protected BaseCreateQuery(SqlObject objectStr) {
        this._object = objectStr;
    }

    public ThisType setName(String name) {
        return this.setCustomName(name);
    }

    public ThisType setCustomName(Object name) {
        this._object = Converter.toCustomSqlObject(name);
        return (BaseCreateQuery)this.getThisType();
    }

    public ThisType addColumns(Column... columns) {
        return this.addCustomColumns((Object[])columns);
    }

    protected void collectSchemaObjects(ValidationContext vContext) {
        super.collectSchemaObjects(vContext);
        this._object.collectSchemaObjects(vContext);
        this._columns.collectSchemaObjects(vContext);
    }

    public void validate(ValidationContext vContext) throws ValidationException {
        super.validate(vContext);
        if (SelectQuery.hasAllColumns(this._columns)) {
            throw new ValidationException("Cannot use the '*' syntax in this query");
        }
    }

    public abstract ThisType addCustomColumns(Object... var1);

    public abstract DropQuery getDropQuery();
}
```

I want to know what is meant by ThisType (in line 1). Is it something to do with Generics in Java. I studied Generics in Java but I did not find a reference to ThisType. TypeScript has the ThisType construct. Is that similar to ThisType in Java?

Comment: `ThisType` is just a name. You can rewrite it as `class BaseCreateQuery<T extends BaseCreateQuery<T>> extends Query<T>` and it won't matter.

Comment: 'Is it something to do with Generics in Java' - that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed its related to Generics. This is a type of the builder (this query is actually a builder) with a generified parameter called `ThisType`. It could be called `T` instead, so nothing special about it. However, `ThisType` is used to emphasize what the parameter actually is.

In general, parameterized build is quite an advanced concept, if you really want to delve into the way of using builders like this consider reading [this article](https://medium.com/@hazraarka072/fluent-builder-and-powering-it-up-with-recursive-generics-in-java-483005a85fcd) for example